# AUTO Silent install script to get past "Configuring grub-efi-amd64"

Tags: grub

I am attempting to complete a silent upgrade script from ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04

Here is the catch:

- I am using a local Landscape Repository 16.04/18.04
- The Clients cannot go out to the Ubuntu repository due to security.
- The systems due to there usage cannot have the UI updated.
- Everything needs to stay as is on the original systems
- We pretty much have the script written and it seems to work fine
- But we get hung at the portion where it asks if we want to modify the `/etc/default/grub`

Does anyone know how to get past this point?

We have attempted many different approaches. Here is our script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# Help ensure that nothing hangs waiting for input when running the apt commands

#echo 'DPkg::options { "--force-confold"; }' >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/local
#echo 'DPkg::options { "--force-confdef"; }' >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/local

# Update the apt package itself, and then initiate the release upgrade 
sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y --only-upgrade apt  && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive && sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::=--force-confdef  -y --allow-unauthenticated dist-upgrade

sed -ri 's/(\[daemon\])/\1\nAutomaticLoginEnable = true\nAutomaticLogin = "computer-name"\n/' /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
sed -i 's/^APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";/APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "0";/' /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic
sed -i 's/^APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";/APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "0";/' /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades
sudo -u meds-6300-yl -- echo "yes" > /home/meds-6300-yl/.config/gnome-initial-setup-done

sed -i 's/Prompt=.*/Prompt=never/g' /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
sudo -u meds-6300-yl -- gsettings set com.ubuntu.update-notifier no-show-notifications true
sudo -u meds-6300-yl -- gsettings set com.ubuntu.update-notifier regular-auto-launch-interval 99999
sudo -u meds-6300-yl -- gsettings set com.ubuntu.update-manager check-dist-upgrades false
sudo -u meds-6300-yl -- gsettings set com.ubuntu.update-manager check-new-release-ignore 'focal'
```

Comment: I don't think this is the source of your problem but it's worth noting that the **redirection** on the `sudo -u meds-6300-yl` command will be done **as the user running sudo**, not as root, because the redirection is being done by the user's shell, not by sudo.   To redirect to a file as root, use `meds-6300-yl -- echo "yes" | sudo tee /home/meds-6300-yl/.config/gnome-initial-setup-done`.  or `sudo meds-6300-yl ... | sudo tee ...` if meds-6300-yl also needs to be run as root.

Comment: Ok Thanks My biggest issue is getting past this hurdle.

Comment: i forgot to mention, `tee`'s job is to copy stdin to both stdout and a file.  if you want to suppress the output, redirect it to /dev/null - `meds-6300-yl ... | sudo tee /home/meds-6300-yl/.config/gnome-initial-setup-done > /dev/null`.   and if you want to append rather than overwrite (i.e. like a `>>`  redirection rather than `>`), use tee's `-a` option.

Comment: Thanks I can get back to that part. Right now I'm stuck . All my attempts on the script work but as soon as it gets to the grub.efi it hangs there. If i can find a way to get that question answered automatically the upgrade should complete

Comment: have you tried adding `export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` to the start of your script (after the #! line, of course)?

Comment: actually, scrolling to the right, I see you are setting that variable, but not exporting it (and as a separate command before an `&&`  rather than as part of the `sudo apt-get` command).  That won't work (variables that aren't exported or set as part of a command aren't available to child processes), either include it as part of each apt-get command or (easier) just export it once at the beginning of the script (and remove it from everywhere else).

Comment: BTW, I very strongly recommend adding linefeeds and indentation to your scripts to make them more readable.  it makes spotting bugs like this much easier.  remember that bash continues a line on the following line if the ends with a backslash, an `&&` or an `||`.   A very long line is a PITA to read.  A series of shorter, indented & continued lines is much easier.